# Sending SMS from mobile to gsm module through lpc2148

Tags: c, gsm, lpc, sim900, arm7

I am trying to do an electronic notice board i.e E-NOTICE BOARD using lpc2148 and gsm module. Here basically, I'm trying to send an sms from a mobile phone through GSM and I want it to be displayed on the LCD screen.

I'm using SIM900A GSM module. I'm able to get the code everywhere for sending a message to the phone from GSM, but receiving code is hardly available anywhere.

It's really important and it would be helpful if anyone can provide the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.smssolutions.net/tutorials/gsm/receivesmsat/ tells you how to use AT commands to receive sms. The ring indicator will probably be set low when an sms is received.

Answer (score 0):

JUST change the mode using the AT commands below. The code will redirect each incoming message on your sim900  module to the uart port. Now you can do whatever with the message.

> AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0